# Solve Quadratically Constrained Linear Objective Function in R

Tags: r, excel, mathematical-optimization, solver, quadratic-programming

### Context

A bit of context is in order. I am currently migrating an Excel tool (sigh!) to n Shiny app. Excel is using the solver Addin to find an "optimal" solution. Now I am looking for a method to do the same in R.

### Analyzing the Objective Function

I did my homework and analyzed the function currently "optimized" in Excel and saw that it can be formalized as a linear objective function with a quadratic constraint, that is, I am effectively trying to optimize this program:

```
     min P'x
s.t. x'Qx + q'x >= a given const
     0 <= x <= 1 (piecewise)
```

Currently my problem involves just 2 variables and I tried to solve it in R using `library(optiSolve)`:

```r
library(optiSolve)

Q <- matrix(c(0, 3897.6, 3897.6, 0), 2)
q <- matrix(c(2, 0), ncol = 1)
P <- matrix(c(1.24, 10), ncol = 1)
x_cur <- matrix(c(0.1, 0.01), ncol = 1)

ref_val <- t(x_cur) %*% Q %*% x_cur + t(q) %*% x_cur 

of <- linfun(P)
qc <- quadcon(-Q, -q, val = -ref_val)
lb <- lbcon(rep(0, ncol(Q)))
ub <- ubcon(rep(1, ncol(Q)))

mod <- cop(of, qc = qc, lb = lb, ub = ub)
solvecop(mod, quiet = TRUE)
# No solution exists.
# $x
#             1             2 
# -0.0000219045 -0.0005667524 
# 
# $solver
# [1] "cccp2"
#
# $status
# [1] "No solution exists."
```

However, the solver is able find a slightly better solution `(0.0909556361478811, 0.0110198817266055)` with the following settings:

[image: Excel solver settings]

(`K3:K4` hold the variables to change (`x`), `C7` calculates the quadratic form, `B7` holds my reference value and `C8` is the linear objective function).

```r
x_excel <- matrix(c(0.0909556361478811, 0.0110198817266055), ncol = 1)
all.equal(t(x_excel) %*% Q %*% x_excel + t(q) %*% x_excel, ref_val,
          tolerance = 0.000001) # excel solver tolerance
# [1] TRUE
c(t(P) %*% x_cur > t(P) %*% x_excel)
# [1] TRUE
all(x_excel >= 0 & x_excel <= 1)
# [1] TRUE
```

### Goal

I am fully aware that Excel simply uses another solver ( `GRG2` if I am not mistaken) and also that my constraint matrix is not positive (semi-) definite.

Thus, it seems that despite my problem is a QC, I cannot rely on dedicated solvers. Hence, I need to solve it differently. I do not need a global optimum, a local one would be fine. Ideally, I could use the same solver to the twin problem, where we want to maximize the Quadratic form, while the linear element becomes a constraint.

My naive approach would be to use `optim` and add the quadratic constraint as a penalty to the objective function, but this feels very hackish and i fear scaling effects need to be considered carefully (the linear funciton and the quadratic form are not at all on the same scale).

How could I get a (local) optimum with R with a quadratic constraint?

Comment: Have you tried using a different solver in solvecop?

Comment: Wow, so easy and indeed both `slsgp` and `alabama` deliver a solution. I will need some further testing ito see whether a simple switch will work, but thanks for pointing to the obvious (which I obvisously overlooked ;))

Comment: Looks like a non-convex problem (depending on how Q exactly looks like). It's not so strange that different solvers find different solutions.

Comment: Yes, as said I cannot guarantee  positive (semi-) definiteness, hence my problem is not (necessarily) convex.  As being everything but an expert of optimization problems, which solvers seem to be suitable for this use case? (quadratic constraint / objective function with a linear constraint / objective function, when the quadratic form is not necessarily positive semidefinite?

Comment: There are four classes of solvers: (1) solvers that  **require** convexity, (2) local solvers that accept non-convex models but return a local optimum, (3) stochastic global solvers find global solutions but no guarantee about quality, (4) deterministic global solvers that can find proven global solutions (under some assumptions). Sometimes we use (2) with a multistart approach (run the solver with many different starting points).

Comment: Very insightful (if you bother to make it an answer, I'll happily accept it) +1 As said a local optimum would be good enough for me, henc I assume (2) - (3) seem to be my best bets. Any R packages you are ware of providing these solvers? (I am aware of and read the optimization task view on CRAN, but I must admit it is rather technical and difficult for me to judge which solvers would be suitable in my case w/o testing them one by one.